# Safari console.log show all entries

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a javascript array with about 300 entries and whenever I want to print it with console.log in the Safari console I can see the index 0 to 99 and thats it. How can I show the other entries?

In Chrome everything works fine, it shows a block with index 0 to 99, then a block from 100 - 199 and so on...

But on safari there is only one block from 0 to 99.

Is it possible that Safari only shows the first 100 entries?

Comment: Did you try [`console.table()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) ?

Comment: Yep same problem only shows 0 to 99...

Comment: The best solution I've found is to use a for loop in the console to print your whole array or whichever subset you need. It's annoying and silly, but so is Safari something