# Safari Console only shows 100 elements of array

Tags: react-native-ios

I have a react-native ios app, and to debug it I've started using Safari, as it is easier than Chrome (have to start Chrome with web security disabled for it to work).
I have a problem however with viewing arrays in the Safari Console, similar to this problem: [Safari console.log show all entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413642/safari-console-log-show-all-entries)
I use `console.log()` to log an array, and the array clearly shows that it has 562 elements, but in the console it only shows 100 of them.
Anyone know how to make Safari show the entire array?